# Passing parameters to custom RESTful routes in Rails (using :collection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to add a custom route to my RESTful routes using the `:collection` param on `map.resources` like so:

```
map.resources :products, :collection => { :tagged => :get }
```

The tagged action takes in a :tag parameter.  I am able to link to the URL route using:
`tagged_products_path(:tag => tag.name)`.  My issue with this is that the URL that this generates:

```
/products/tagged?tag=electronic
```

I would like the tag to be in the URL and not the tag, like so:

```
/products/tagged/electronic
```

Of course this can be accomplished by a separate named route, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something and there is a way to do this with the `:collection` hash.

Thanks in advance for your help

-Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collection routes don't support this - you'll have to use a named route.

```
map.tagged_products '/products/tagged/:tag', 
  :controller => 'products', :action => 'tagged', :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the answer is for Rails 2, I just wanted to add the Rails 4 version of this.

```
get '/products/tagged/:tag' => 'products#tagged', as: :tagged_products
```

This would be used as

```
tagged_products_path('electronic') #=> "/products/tagged/electronic"
```

Answer (score 1):

Collection routes do not support this but there is a workaround.

```
"#{tagged_products_path}?#{{:tag => tag.name}.to_query}}"
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if context was provided, e.g. "add this to your model code" or "this should go in your routes.rb".

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are no longer accurate with regard to the latest version of Rails. See [Rails3 Routes - Passing parameter to a member route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271023/rails3-routes-passing-parameter-to-a-member-route)