# Rails3 Routes - Passing parameter to a member route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I would like to pass an extra parameter to a member route of a resource

something like:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get 'register/:participant_type_id'
  end
end
```

I could only accomplish it using a static match statement

Looking around the internet I saw that this might be possible in Rails 3.0.2. I'm using 3.0.1 and it certanlly is not.

Am I doing something wrong? or is it really not possible?

thanks

Comment: This is supposed to be possible with 3.0.1, are you getting an error?

Comment: found this, not sure if its related ... https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5431-rails-3-rc-routing-resource-member-routes-lack-defaults

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get 'register/:participant_type_id', :action => 'register'
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know, I just supply whatever my app tells me it's missing. It said 'missing action', I give them action.

Answer (score 18):

Just to complete the answer with my little findings. It also confused me for quite a while.

In Rails3, the member route with parameters will not have the automatic generated `xx_yy_path` helper. You need to add it providing the `:as =>` part, omitted the `resources` name.

Regarding the example provided, to get `register_event_path` and `register_event_url`, you need to define it like the following:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get 'register/:participant_type_id', :action => 'register', :as => 'register'
  end
end
```

Comment: how to get an event id inside of register action?

Comment: @lessless within `resources :events` and `member` I believe an `id` parameter representing `event id` is automatically in the generated path.