# Rails - Member Action with Parameter - path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, helper, view-helpers

I saw this post about adding parameters to a member action route:

[Rails3 Routes - Passing parameter to a member route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271023/rails3-routes-passing-parameter-to-a-member-route)

And the routing works great when I enter the full URL manually: www.whatever.com/resource/:resource_id/action/:action_parameter

Is there a convenient path helper I can use to link to this in my views?  For example, if it is just an ordinary member action WITHOUT a parameter, I can use

action_resource_path(:resource_id)

Is there an equivalent with the extra parameter?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a url helper with the `as` option:

```
resources :foos do
  collection do
    get 'bar/:resource_id', :action => :bar, :as => 'bar'
  end
end
```

The route that gets generated will look like:

```
$ rake routes | grep bar
bar_foos GET    /foos/bar/:resource_id(.:format)         {:action=>"bar", :controller=>"foos"}
```

You can use that like:

```
bar_foos_path(:resource_id => @resource.id)
```