# Changing a Rails Route to include another model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ecommerce site in Rails 4 where the product listing routes are based on 'resources listings'. This makes the listing show pages routes as /listing/:id. I want to include the product name in the route and make it be /listing/:id/:name - how would I do this.

I saw the friendlyid gem but I'd prefer doing this without a gem, if there is a simple way.

Here is listings route block:

```
  resources :listings do
        collection do
          post 'import'
          get 'search'
          get 'delete_all'
        end
   resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show]
  end
```

Per Jorge's answer below, I added a `get '/:name' => 'listings#show'` but when I do rake routes, I get an error saying 'Could not find listing without an ID' and I still see the original route /listings/:id pointing to listings#show.

Update:
When I paste the new route as above, the default routes when I click on a product is still /listings/:id. However, when I type in the new route /listings/:id/:name (e.g. listings/324/testlisting) I get an error as below:

```
Started GET "/listings/324/brand" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-29 12:55:35 -0700
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"listing_id"=>"324", "name"=>"brand"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing without an ID):
  app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:189:in `set_listing'
```

The 'set_listing' method just finds the listing based on the id. here is part of the listings controller.

```
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: The param is named: listing_id, but you are searching of [:id] in Listing.find(params[:id]). That's why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

[Rails3 Routes - Passing parameter to a member route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271023/rails3-routes-passing-parameter-to-a-member-route)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
resources :listing do
  get '/:name', to 'listings#whatever'
end
```

EDIT:

Does your routes look like these?

```
  resources :listings do
    get '/:name', :to => 'listings#show'
    collection do
      post 'import'
      get 'search'
      get 'delete_all'
    end
    resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show]
  end
```

EDIT 2:

I recomend creating a new method:

```
def show_by_name
   @listing = Listing.find_by(name: params[:name])
   render action: 'show'
end
```

And use it on the route:

```
get '/:name', :to => 'listings#show_by_name'
```

Comment: This gives me an error `Couldn't find Listing without an ID`

Comment: Paste the params that are being passed to the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find what is being passed. I just updated my post to include my code block and some other details.

Comment: Check if the routes file looks like the edited answer.

Comment: Paste complete error stack trace to find out what's wrong with the id. rake routes should just return the routes, not try to find anything.

Comment: You are passing a param: listing_id and using another one in the method: :id.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I'm not sure why that is happening. All I did was add your route. The default id param is :id. The error occurred when I typed in the url /listings/324/brand - 324 is the :id and brand is the name of the test product.

Comment: Edited with another option. I don't know why it's changing the :id to :listing_id. Perhaps some internal rails mechanism. Use the edited answer.

Comment: That still wouldn't solve the issue that the urls on the products are still listings/:id. The error occurred when j manually typed in the new url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63893/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-moosa).

Comment: Sorry I had to step away for a bit. Let me get back to you after I play with it a bit. I might try the friendly id gem as well.